# Flex-Basis: Force Children to have fixed size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I'm sorry, I checked out multiple answers but nothing seems to work. If somebody could point me into the right direction, that would be helpful!

I have a Wrapper and 8 Boxes:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>

  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>
  <Box></Box>
</Wrapper>
```

I want my Flex Wrapper to break after 4 Boxes, so I want to have 4 Boxes in a row. I have solved this in the following way:

Wrapper:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;`;
```

Box:

```
const Box = styled.div`
  background-color: gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;`;
  flex: 1 0 21%;`;
```

However, I'd like my Boxes to not stretch, I'd like them to **always be** `150x150px`. Right now they're stretching and they're not 150x150 - I don't know what to do though?

Comment: Just remove the `flex` property completely. It's not necessary in this instance.

Comment: It won't break after 4 Items then though

Comment: Not `display:flex` --- remove this --> `flex: 1 0 21%`

Comment: Yes, I got that. But now it's no wrapping up my items after exactly four.

Comment: So what do you expect...either you want a fixed size for these elements or not. Wrapping is a separate issue.  Your container size will determine when the elements wrap. What layout are you trying to achieve? Are these elements supposed to be centered or something?

Comment: Yeah exactly. I want a row of 4 Boxes, another row of 4 Boxes, all in a div thats centered. On smaller viewports i'd like to have only 1 box, on medium 2 boxes in a row. Really struggling with this.

Comment: There's no real layout method that will do that for you dynamically without a whole bunch of media queries. You'd need to adjust the max-width of the container to adjust for the width of the contents *plus* any accumulated margins...at each break point - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PoqGdNy

Comment: Okay. Thank you!